# Bind to a substring in sap.m.label

Tags: json, binding, sapui5

I need to bind only the first 10 letters of a string to my label.

I did not find any solution so far except from this:

```
<m:Text text="{Name1/0}{Name1/1}{Name1/2}{Name1/3}{Name1/4}{Name1/5} {.../9}" />
```

This seems pretty ugly and inefficient - is there a better way to do this ?

Is it also possible to get the last 10 letters ?

**NOTE:** I would like to do this without a `Formatter`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The binding syntax of SAPUI5 provides support for basic JavaScript expressions.

Consider a model property `myProp` holding the string value `Hello world`:

The plain binding will output the value as usual:
`<Text text="{myProp}" />` *Hello World*

Using "Expression Binding" syntax you can add some flexibility without introducing a formatter. The syntax for printing the same property, but with expression binding, looks like this:

`<Text text="{= ${myProp} }" />` *Hello World*

`{= ... }` The equals sign indicates you want expressions to be evaluated. To access binding variables within the expression, use `${myProp}`

**Examples:**
`text="{= ${myProp}.substr(0,5) }"` *Hello*
`text="{= ${myProp}.length }"` *11*
`text="{= ${myProp}.length > 5 ? 'foo' : 'bar' }"` *foo*
`text="{= ${myProp} + ' has ' ${myProp}.length + ' chars'}"` *Hello World has 11 chars*

A list of possible operators can be found in the SAPUI5 developer guide: [Expression Binding](https://openui5beta.hana.ondemand.com/1.46.10/#docs/guide/daf6852a04b44d118963968a1239d2c0.html)